# UNION on two select gives 'SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis'

Tags: sql, oracle, union, ora-00907

I'm trying to UNION the results of two queries. But I'm getting the following error:

```
Error at Command Line:9 Column:81
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT application_id, clicks, datee, client_id FROM(
(select 
    APPL_CD AS application_id, 
    count(*) as clicks, 
    to_date((to_char(ACTN_TAKE_DATA_TM, 'dd-mm-yyyy')), 'dd-mm-yyyy') as datee, 
    ALRT_RSPNS_FROM_CLIENT_ID AS client_id 
from  ALRT_PLATFORM_ALRT_HSTRY
    where  ACTN_TAKE_CD is not null 
    group by to_char(ACTN_TAKE_DATA_TM, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), APPL_CD, ALRT_RSPNS_FROM_CLIENT_ID order by datee) 
UNION ALL
(select 
    APPL_CD AS application_id, 
    count(*) as clicks, 
    to_date((to_char(ACTN_TAKE_DATA_TM, 'dd-mm-yyyy')), 'dd-mm-yyyy') as datee, 
    ALRT_RSPNS_FROM_CLIENT_ID AS client_id 
from  ALRT_PLATFORM_ALRT
    where  ACTN_TAKE_CD is not null 
    group by to_char(ACTN_TAKE_DATA_TM, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), APPL_CD, ALRT_RSPNS_FROM_CLIENT_ID order by datee )
)
```

Comment: It seems, there is no parenthesis mismatch.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the `ORDER BY` from the nested queries:

```
SELECT application_id, clicks, datee, client_id FROM(
(select 
    APPL_CD AS application_id, 
    count(*) as clicks, 
    to_date((to_char(ACTN_TAKE_DATA_TM, 'dd-mm-yyyy')), 'dd-mm-yyyy') as datee, 
    ALRT_RSPNS_FROM_CLIENT_ID AS client_id 
from  ALRT_PLATFORM_ALRT_HSTRY
    where  ACTN_TAKE_CD is not null 
    group by to_char(ACTN_TAKE_DATA_TM, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), APPL_CD, ALRT_RSPNS_FROM_CLIENT_ID) 
UNION ALL
(select 
    APPL_CD AS application_id, 
    count(*) as clicks, 
    to_date((to_char(ACTN_TAKE_DATA_TM, 'dd-mm-yyyy')), 'dd-mm-yyyy') as datee, 
    ALRT_RSPNS_FROM_CLIENT_ID AS client_id 
from  ALRT_PLATFORM_ALRT
    where  ACTN_TAKE_CD is not null 
    group by to_char(ACTN_TAKE_DATA_TM, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), APPL_CD, ALRT_RSPNS_FROM_CLIENT_ID )
)
```

Comment: @cedar715: because `Oracle` does not support `ORDER BY` in the nested queries. The resulting order is not guaranteed anyway.

Comment: WHY?! I wanted to combine two pre-ordered result set so that set A appears above set B (figuratively). But I can only apply ORDER BY for set A. If I try to apply ORDER BY on set B, it says 'missing right parenthesis'. Why is it allowed on set A then? How can I have both sets ordered individually without introducing an ordering key to do final ordering with?

Comment: Never mind, I figured that if you nest the query like `SELECT * FROM ( /* set B query with ORDER BY */ )` you can have set B ordered, and it won't give the error :D

Comment: @ADTC: without final `ORDER BY`, the final ordering is not guaranteed, even if both your sets are ordered. In fact, if they are both ordered, the optimizer will likely choose `MERGE UNION` method which will not preserve "A then B" order.

Comment: @Quassnoi thanks. Is there a correct way to preserve the "A then B" order? In my tests of `UNION ALL` it seems to preserve it and not mix it up, but that can just be a coincidence (the Explain Plan doesn't mention `MERGE UNION`). Maybe I could do conditional sorting as a final `ORDER BY` instead of sorting in subqueries, yea?

Comment: @ADTC: yes, that's exactly what you should do.

Comment: @ADTC: see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8fedc/1. I forced the optimizer to use `MERGE UNION`, and, as you can see, the tables' records are all mixed up. `ORDER BY` is the only guaranteed way to order results.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I had decided to do final ordering using `ORDER BY` to guarantee the order. With some tricks like `ORDER BY CASE WHEN ~ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC`, I can get the correct ordering I desire `:D` It's all good now. Thank you for your kind help!